# Can I use range of str to get a loop of 12 months?

Tags: python, string, loops

I would like to use this loop-function for all 12 months. Any idea how to alter the date, tried with a string of values, but I am just lost. Thankful for inputs.

```
y=str('02','03','04') # Months (Can I use Range here in some way?)
q=('01.'+(y)+'.'+(year)) # Date in file, where the loop break

with open('f.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if z in line: # Work after this line "z"
            i=0
            c=0
            temp_y=[] # Create empty list
            for line in f:
                temp_1= float((line.split()[i+8])) # Read every 8:th element in file
                temp_y.append(temp_1) # Adds a new value at the neareast empty spot
                c += 1 # For average equation
                print(temp_1)
                if q in line: # (This is where I am stuck)
                    break
```

Comment: `["{:02}.".format(i) for i in range(1,13)]` or `'.'.join(["{:02}".format(i) for i in range(1,13)])+".2016"` if I understand what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    month = '%02d' % month
    print('01.' + month + '.' + '2016')
```

Here is another:

```
months = ['%02d' % month for month in range(1, 13)]
print (months)
```

Comment: Great! Fantastic! Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through an array of strings, you don't need range.

```
Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
for mo in Months:
    print mo
```

If you are just looking for how to pick out the month field from the date.

```
date='01.11.2016'
print date.split('.')[1]
'11'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do not have time to try it out :)